# How to retrieve state of custom views?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have created custom view `ComplexView` with `EditText` inside. I have fragment `DetailsFragment` with 3 `ComplexView`s in his layout. When I entered values (A,B,C) in my `DetailsFragment` and then push and pop an fragment all editTexts have the same value C. I implemented own version of `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` and it doesn't help. What is wrong?

```
@Override
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(STATE_SUPER_STATE, super.onSaveInstanceState());
    bundle.putString(STATE_DESCRIPTION_TEXT, mDescription.getText().toString());

    return bundle;
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    if (state instanceof Bundle) {
        Bundle bundle = (Bundle)state;

        super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle.getParcelable(STATE_SUPER_STATE));
        mDescription.setText(bundle.getString(STATE_DESCRIPTION_TEXT));
    } else {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think we need to see some more code.  How is the data entered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this occurs is that the `EditText` within each instance of your `ComplexView` shares an ID with every other instance of that View. When your `ComplexView` dispatches save/restore events to it's children, things get a little funky with Views that share the same ID.

To fix this, you need to block the dispatch of state saving/restoration to your `ComplexView`'s children in addition to override the save and restore methods.

You can do this like so:

```
@Override
protected void dispatchSaveInstanceState(SparseArray<Parcelable> container) {
    dispatchFreezeSelfOnly(container);
}

@Override
protected void dispatchRestoreInstanceState(SparseArray<Parcelable> container) {
    dispatchThawSelfOnly(container);
}
```

Now when your `ComplexView` restores or saves it's state it will *only* save or restore it's own state; you are telling it that you will handle saving and restoring the children yourself.

Cyril Mottier just posted some good slides on this [here](https://speakerdeck.com/cyrilmottier/deep-dive-into-android-state-restoration). The piece referring to this issue is about 80% of the way in.